# How to hide theme feature in a custom css box wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, class

`class="hero-play-btn various fancybox.iframe"`

Is it possible to hide the above class in a custom css box in wordpress?

It is coded in by the theme we are using. And I have no need for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a child theme in wordpress, and set `display:none` for the elements you don't need from a stylesheet within the child theme.

Read more on child themes and how to make them here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

If you have direct access to the theme installed, you can find and hide/remove the elements. Be aware that any changed to a theme will be undone if the theme is updated in the future. Hence why we use child themed for such tasks